# how can we make a div take width according to its content automatically

Tags: html, width, fieldset

I want to create an effect like that of `fieldset` and `label`.

[image]

When the headings change along the side, the width that the white background of the heading remains the same.

If I can make the `heading` or `div` element to take the width enough to fit its content, it will give the proper effect.

If there is any other solution please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `float` on the div you want to shrink, or `display: inline-block` (though that won't work in IE6 (since it applies `inline-block` only to elements inline by default) without specifying a width. Or you can use both, obviously. Though I'm not sure why you'd want to make a floated-block act as if it was `inline`.

Demo at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/esora3/)

Comment: display inline-block does the job

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend this

```
#element {
    display: table; /* IE8+ and all other modern browsers */
}
```